# Can someone help in writing Java program to download Sharepoint Lists?

Tags: java, sharepoint

I wrote below program to download SharePoint lists.  But I am getting errors while using sharepointclient and listsoapstub. Does they have any dependency on other API's or jar files ? If so, what will be those ?

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SimpleAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{

      private final String username;
      private final char[] password;

      public SimpleAuthenticator(final String username, final String password)
      {
            super();
            this.username = new String(username);
            this.password = password.toCharArray();
      }

      @Override
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
      {

                return (new PasswordAuthentication (username, password));
      }
}
```

> SimpleAuthenticator authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator(username,
>   password);
>       Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

```
public class SPClient
{

      private static String username = "your sharepoint username";
      private static String password = "your sharepoinnt password";
      private static String BasesharepointUrl = "https://mysharepoint.com/Book Names";
      private static ListsSoap listsoapstub;
      private static VersionsSoap versionssoapstub;
      private static CopySoap copysoapstub;

      private static SharePointClient getInstance()
      {
          return(new SharePointClient());
      }
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          try
          {

              NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);
              Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

              //Authenticating and Opening the SOAP port of the Copy Web Service
              listsoapstub = SharePointClient.getSPListSoapStub(username, password, BasesharepointUrl);

              // Displays the lists items in the console
              SharePointClient.displaySharePointList();

          } 
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
              System.err.println(ex);
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the errors?

Comment: "versionSoap" not resolved, "CopySoap" not resolved, "sharepointclient" not resolved, and "listsoapstub" not resolved.


The public type "SimpleAuthenticator" must be defined in it's own file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you got the code that you "wrote" from here:

- http://blog.ashwani.co.in/blog/2013-07-28/connect-and-access-sharepoint-webservice-from-java/

(Your code looks strikingly similar to that code!)

I think the answer to your question is covered in these described in that blog posting:

- Step 1. Download the wsdl files from the sharepoint.
- Step 2. Generate Java Stubs for these wsdls
- Step 3. Place the WSDLs in your resources

Once you have done that, you should be able to add imports for the relevant classes to the classes that you wrote.

Comment: Yes, I took the code from the mentioned site.. does it need any dependency jars ??

Comment: And should I create the normal Java project or web project ??

Comment: Can you provide the weblink where I can download all the required WSDL files.

Comment: As the blog explains, you download them from your Sharepoint server.